# approach use for text hanlding

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, uicollectionviewcell, nsattributedstring

I am working on an app which have around 7000 records. For the data handling we are using coredata. The basic structure of the entity is, we have arabic title and its english translation.

For example let say:
title in arabic : translation in english

Now our app has two modes:

- Show translation
- Show only titles

For mode show translation we are displaying translation and title side by side in a single `UITableViewCell` and `NSFetchedResultController` is used to display the records in `UITableView`. (This is good)

**What i want**

For show title only mode:

We have to show text in a **continuous manner** like in `UITextView`.
For example:

- Record 1 = This is record 1
- Record 2 = This is record 2
- Record 3 = This is record 3

I want it be display as **This is record 1. This is record 2. This is record 3** and so on (i.e concatenation)

I cannot use `UITextView` for the following reasons:

- I have to concatenate 7000 records (which is a pretty heavy process)
- Setting that large text on `UITextView` is taking very long time.

So what approach should i use to show records in a sentence format?

Like in the screenshot below:

[image]

Comment: If u use NSArray method componentsJoinedByString will that help to speed up your concatenation. Basically u would like to show your all records in sentence format

Comment: Yes i want to show records in a sentence format.
It is taking too long because i have records in bulk amount.

Comment: If u load your text in array from core and if u use NSArray method NSString strText= [array componentsJoinedByString " "]  this will give you all concatenated string. I hope it helps try and see wether it is fast or not?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a thought: what if you updated the `UITextView` while you're concatenating the strings. For example, update the text in the view after every 100th record has been concatenated. This would solve your problem with it taking a long time to display, because it would add the text in smaller pieces instead of waiting for the whole operation to finish. I'm not sure how the performance would be, though. You'd have to try it out.